# Usage of jQuery Tags script, save and retrieve data

Tags: php, jquery, tags, jquery-textext

I am using jQuery tags script http://textextjs.com/

The problem i am encountering is when the data is saved and then retrieved from my database. I can't get new tags to append or saved tags to display properly. Below is my code:

```
<input class="span8" id="tagname" placeholder="Enter A Tag" type="text">
<button id="addtag" type="button">Add</button>

<form method="post" action="classes/update.affid.php">
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="update_user_tags" />
<textarea id="textarea" name="tags" rows="1">
    <?php echo $edituser->getField('tags');?>
</textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Save Tags">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$('#textarea').textext({ plugins: 'tags' });
$('#addtag').bind('click', function(e)
{
    $('#textarea').textext()[0].tags().addTags([ $('#tagname').val() ]);
    $('#tagname').val('');
});
</script>
```

Everything works fine on first load.
Once i save the data to the DB it is now displayed like:

["one","two","three","four","five"]

Then if remove the data and save, i get:

[]

How do i get the textext plugin to run run on the textarea properly?

Comment: We can't see `update.affid.php` . We can't see where you save : `Once i save the data to the DB` . You have a `<input>` Tag outside a `<form>` Tag ?  What's the use of it ?

Comment: The input field outside the form is controlled by the javascipt and adds a value to the the textarea.

Comment: i found another plug-in that is easier to use with my PHP. https://github.com/xoxco/jQuery-Tags-Input

Comment: You did not explain how you store / delete /store , the data into Database.